# What is the dependency to be used in maven project using new version of Selenium 3.5

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, dependencies

What is the dependency to be used in the pom.xml file related to  maven project using new version of Selenium 3.5 that are launched in 10/08/2017?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Maven hasn't updated it's repo with this version of selenium webdriver. (I am assuming you are looking for jar from package org.seleniumhq.selenium ). It will be shorltly updated.
Or you can use this selenium from org.jbehave.web

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jbehave.web/jbehave-web-selenium -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jbehave.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbehave-web-selenium</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: yes , I'm looking for selenium java jars , as I used this in below :3.4.0 version: 
< <dependency> 
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId> 
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId> 
<version>3.4.0</version> 
</dependency>>

Comment: Maven will not update a repo for artifacts that's the job of the maintainers of the things...It would be a good idea to make a ticket at the project...